# Map to collect nodes

Tags: views

I have a content type with +3000 nodes, and it has a field set as Term Reference for countries. I would like to have a map that count all these nodes (maybe with Views), but all solutions I have found was to set a geofield using [Gmap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) module, and in my case it will be hard to go through the +3000 nodes to give each node its location.

So is there is any module that can count nodes of each term, showing it on its country? Also if I would like to show only five countries instead of whole world map, is that a map library or map modules can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't look too complicated, I'd normally use the following modules to easily add and display nodes on a map:

- Leaflet;
- Leaflet Views;
- Leaflet More Maps;
- Views;
- Geofield;
- Geocoder;
- Geocoder Autocomplete;
- GeoPHP;
- Entity;
- Entity Reference;
- Chosen;

I don't work with Taxonomy terms. Instead, I create a node type named, let's say "Category" and add the right categories as nodes instead of terms in a vocabulary. It is easier like this and offers me more flexibility in the future.

The Category content type is based on a form that only includes Title as field. I'm adding them manually, which is not as simple as adding tags (terms) with the autocomplete options. As an alternative, I think you could use Inline Entity Form to add Categories during node add form. Not sure though.

When adding nodes, you need:

- an entity reference field pointing to the Category (using Chosen could help, if you don't have 10k categories);
- a textfield using Geocoder text field with autocomplete;
- a Geofield using Geocode from another field.

Now, when adding nodes, you get the Google Geocoder autocomplete option and the geofield will auto-fill with the right coordinates.

Then, I'm using Views to display items on the map with Leaflet. Here you can choose displaying only first 5 items, based on whatever filter criteria and order options you'd like. The view is a block and has an Entity Reference relationship poiting from the node to the category node + a contextual filter NID type my-node-type, with content ID from URL argument that uses this relationship.

Block will show up only on Category node-type pages in the content area.

Doesn't look very simple but there are a few tutorials on how to achieve that with leaflet, geofield and entities on Youtube. There are other ways to solve your problem, like using EVA with DS, adding blocks as fields in your DS display.

Comment: That is very detailed, but the problem that there's already nodes stored to the Taxonomy (which has country terms). I have tried to add Geo fields that you mentioned to the Term itself, and adding a Term view to show count of nodes in each term, but actually nothing came out, not even the map, any idea?

Comment: That's pretty awesome actually.

You can use the default view provided for taxonomy terms, just activate it from your list. That's one view listing teasers or whatever you may choose. Attach another view to the existing one, after or before (Views Attachment) and change display to Leaflet Maps. You still need to use Geofield in your nodes for leaflet to work. And you still need to add coordinates to that field. Thats where geocoder and autocomplete jumps in.

The only difference here is the relationship. You will use taxonomy with term instead of entity reference.

Good luck!

Comment: You may need help for the other issue - counting nodes for each respective term. I would go for aggregation in views to achieve that. Bottom line here, What you want, if you don't know hot to do it, it could take ages. Other than that, this isn't something you cannot do, even without coding.